# Drupal 8 - sending files to browser via route module

Tags: file, module, controller, routes, drupal-8

I have a module, and inside this module, there should be a new route in the .routing.yml with:

```
path: '/file_exporter/{filename}'
defaults:
  _controller: '\Drupal\file_exporter\Controller\ExportController::file_export'
```

Inside the ExportController, there is happening a bit magic, where a file is created depending on the user and other circumstances, and this works fine, and i have this file in a temp folder inside the module.

**But how could i send it to the browser with drupal?**

Target ist, that i have a link on another site to /fileexporter/file_123.xyz and a click on this link lets the browser directly download the new generated file_123.xyz

**Is there a class which i could extend, or a function that i could use in Drupal 8 to send files direct to browsers via a Route and a Controller?**

Answer (score 2):

The trick is in using [BinaryFileResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/function/BinaryFileResponse%3A%3A__construct/8.2.x).

Here's an example function that handles setting up the HTTP headers and content type and returns a BinaryFileResponse:

```
<?php
// $uri: the file you want to send, as a URI (e.g. private://somefile.txt)
// $ofilename: the output filename, this will be displayed in the browser.
// $contenttype: the mime content type for the browser
// $delete_after_send: delete the file once it's been sent to the browser

function mymodule_transfer_file($uri, $ofilename, $contenttype = NULL, $delete_after_send = FALSE) {

  $mime = \Drupal::service('file.mime_type.guesser')->guess($uri);

  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => $mime . '; name="' . Unicode::mimeHeaderEncode(basename($uri)) . '"',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($uri),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . Unicode::mimeHeaderEncode($ofilename) . '"',
    'Cache-Control' => 'private',
  );

  if (isset($contenttype)) {
    $headers['Content-Type'] = $contenttype;
  }

  if ($delete_after_send) {
    // Delete after end of script.
    drupal_register_shutdown_function('file_unmanaged_delete', $uri);
  }

  $uri_obj = new Uri($uri);
  return new BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers, $uri_obj->getScheme() !== 'private');
}
```